# Test controller from Fixture passing to TESTS

Tags: testing, navigation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am using one condition( if-else loop)  to use different URLs based on the env. I am mentioning this in  fixture.beforeEach(..) and want to hit the URLs in TESTS based on the outcome

```
fixture('Verifying')
       .beforeEach(async t =>{
        console.log("Execution Started ");
        const args = minimist(process.argv.slice(2));
        var environment = args.env;
        if(environment == 'Test')
        {
            t.ctx.Connectionstring=config.Test.Connectionstring;
            t.ctx.Url=config.Test.Url;
        }
        else if(environment == 'Stage')
        {
            t.ctx.Connectionstring=config.Stage.Connectionstring;
            t.ctx.Url=config.Stage.Url;
        }
        else if(environment == 'Prod')
        {
            t.ctx.Connectionstring=config.Prod.Connectionstring;
            t.ctx.Url=config.Prod.Url;
        }


 test.page(t.ctx.Url)
    ("TC1 - Report Batches", async t => {

    await t

    .typeText(lgpage.username, 'abc)
    .typeText(lgpage.password,'abc')
    .click(lgpage.submit)
})
```

test.page(t.ctx.Url) does not work. Even if I give fixture.page(t.ctx.Url) does not work both the time it is giving the error:

"Cannot implicitly resolve the test run in the context of which the test controller action should be executed. Use the test function's 't' argument instead."

I also tried navigateTo(t.ctx.Url) this does not work.

Answer (score 2):

```js
fixture('Verifying')
       .beforeEach(async t =>{
        console.log("Execution Started ");
        const args = minimist(process.argv.slice(2));
        var environment = args.env;
        if(environment == 'Test')
        {
            t.ctx.Connectionstring=config.Test.Connectionstring;
            t.ctx.Url=config.Test.Url;
        }
        else if(environment == 'Stage')
        {
            t.ctx.Connectionstring=config.Stage.Connectionstring;
            t.ctx.Url=config.Stage.Url;
        }
        else if(environment == 'Prod')
        {
            t.ctx.Connectionstring=config.Prod.Connectionstring;
            t.ctx.Url=config.Prod.Url;
        }


 test("TC1 - Report Batches", async t => {
    await t
    .navigateTo(t.ctx.Url)
    .typeText(lgpage.username, 'abc)
    .typeText(lgpage.password,'abc')
    .click(lgpage.submit)
})
```